# ffmpeg ametadata filter's output is correct?

Tags: ffmpeg

I try to detect silence by using ffmpeg with the below command.

```
ffmpeg -i "test.mov" -af silencedetect=noise=-60dB:d=0.5,ametadata=print:file=log.txt -f null -
```

and I got the result below

```
frame:3008 pts:3012663 pts_time:62.7638
lavfi.silence_start=62.2804
frame:3040 pts:3044879 pts_time:63.435
lavfi.silence_end=63.4504
lavfi.silence_duration=1.16996

frame:10230 pts:10244071 pts_time:213.418
lavfi.silence_start=212.925
frame:10523 pts:10536927 pts_time:219.519
lavfi.silence_end=219.524
lavfi.silence_duration=6.59985
```

This input video's fps is 29.97.

The lavfi.silence_start/end shows right result, but frame is incorrect because its framecount is only 8218!

Why this things happened?

There's no way to get the timecode instead this frame information ?

Answer (score 1):

`frame:` here does not refer to video frames. Audio samples are also framed, with number of samples depending on the codec.

AAC is typically 1024 samples/frame. MP3 may be 1152 samples/frame. So, if your sampling rate is 48000 Hz, each AAC audio frame will be of duration `1024/48000 = 0.2133 seconds`.